# Why /MD is compiler's option? not linker's?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, linker, crt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is runtime library a compiler option rather than a linker option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521972/why-is-runtime-library-a-compiler-option-rather-than-a-linker-option)

I do not understand clearly why i have to choose type of RTL 
at the compiling stage?

For example i have created one static library A.lib with option /MD.
Then i've created second static library B.lib with option /MT.

When i try to link A.lib and B.lib to my C.exe
I will get linker error.

But at the compiling stage (creation A.lib and B.lib)
there is no any reasons to resolve symbols from c or c++ runtime.

Comment: Related. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/521972/why-is-runtime-library-a-compiler-option-rather-than-a-linker-option

Comment: The CRT is just not very compatible with it.  Biggest problem are global variables, like errno.  Gets redefined to a function with /MD in effect.

Answer (score 1):

When you build with `/MD`, the compiler uses a different set of predefined macros, then when you build with `/MT`. See [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3.aspx) and pay attention to `_MT`, `_DLL`, etc. macros.

> at the compiling stage (creation A.lib and B.lib) there is no any reasons to resolve symbols from c or c++ runtime.

That is true, but if you include any system headers, your preprocessed source is actually *different* depending on which of `/MD`, `/MT`, etc. flags you've used, and *that* matters very much at compile stage.